# How to get total count of specific key from json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I've below json, I want to filter the model ,sold and count in below manner:

If Model "xyz" already exist in json array, increase the cnt, In this case "xyz" coming three time in below json - so I've to add cnt 5+4+2 = 11 and final output should come as `{laptopModel: "xyz" , sold: "yes" , cnt: "11" }` - How I can do this in jquery?

```
[
  {
    “laptopModel": “xyz",
    “sold": yes,
    “cnt": 5
  },
  {
    “laptopModel": “xyz",
    “sold": yes,
    “cnt": 4
  },
  {
    “laptopModel": “abc",
    “sold": yes,
    “cnt": 3
  },
  {
    “laptopModel": “xyz",
    “sold": yes,
    “cnt": 2
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my solution below

```js
var data = [
      {
        "laptopModel": "xyz",
        "sold": "yes",
        "cnt": 5
      },
      {
        "laptopModel": "xyz",
        "sold": "yes",
        "cnt": 4
      },
      {
        "laptopModel": "abc",
        "sold": "yes",
        "cnt": 3
      },
      {
        "laptopModel": "xyz",
        "sold": "yes",
        "cnt": 2
      }];
var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (!temp[data[i]['laptopModel']]) {
           temp[data[i]['laptopModel']] = data[i];
      } else {
          temp[data[i]['laptopModel']]['cnt'] += data[i]['cnt'];
      }
    }
var result = [];
for (var key in temp) {
   if (temp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var obj = temp[key];
       result.push(obj);
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: its returning empty array :(